# Access DB: Daily cumulative count and daily number on assignment

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a table that tracks the dispatching of personnel.  The table has the employee name and the date the person went out and the date they returned.

The table has hundreds of entries from 1988 to current.
In Excel I track the cumulative count per day (of the year) of how many people have been sent out, and I also track the number of people out on any given day.  The table lists the Month & Day in the first column (every day of the year, including leap days) and the years on the first row.  There is data for every date (a zero is entered until the first person is sent out that year, then starts counting up as there are more dispatches, or in the case of the number of people out each day, it will show zero if no one is out that day or if there were, say 5 people out, it would show "5" for that day).  I then use the data in Excel to construct a graph that shows the number of dispatches on the y axis and the day of the year on the x axis (along with the current year’s number, the average number and the max over the 27 year history).  Currently I just track this manually (I just keep a running count of each and enter it in manually in Excel.)  I would like to build a query of my Access data that would return the same information that I could import into my Excel spreadsheet.  One query that would show the day & month in the first column and the years along the top row and for each day show a cumulative count for that year of how many people have been sent out.  Another query that has the day & month in the first column and the years along the top and a count of how many people were out for that particular day for that particular year.  There shouldn't be any gaps (every day has data, even if it is "0").  I would then import those queries into Excel to replace my manual tracking that I am doing now.

I know how to construct the Excel stuff (I have that running already), and how to import info from Access to Excel, what I need to know is how to construct these 2 Access queries.

Any help/ideas on how to construct those 2 queries would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd recommend migrating this desk drawer application from Excel and Access to a real database and a web app.

Comment: So you currently enter information manually into both an Access database *and* an Excel document? Are you the only person who does the data-entry and reporting?

Comment: Hi Gord...I used to enter all information into Excel, but it was getting out of hand.  I now enter all the dispatch info into Access (I've got tables on the personnel, the places the personnel are sent to and the dispatch information) and I have been able to figure out most of the queries that replace what I was doing in Excel (in terms of reporting information).  The only reporting that I have left to automate would be these last 2 (getting a cumulative count per day for each year and getting the number of personnel out on any given day for each day of the year).

Comment: @duffymo If you'd be so kind, please explain what you mean by "desk drawer application" and your reason(s) for recommending a web application.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you migrate this app to a web based solution that uses a real database - SQL Server or MySQL, not Access.

"Desk drawer software" is what I call homegrown apps that someone creates for themselves to perform some small task that eventually become integral to running a business and grow out of hand. Your truck factor is 1: if anything happened to you, no one would know how to do this function. The software may not be backed up or checked into a source code management system. There's no QA. There's no way to migrate new features to production: if you alter the app, then that is what you have.

I'd recommend a web app to mitigate all the risks I've described:

1. You have to deploy a web app to a server, which takes it off your desktop and puts it in a central place where anyone who's authorized can access it.
2. Separates database from display issues.
3. Makes you think about how to archive historical data.  Partitioning by year makes sense.
4. Likely you'll put this in a source code management system like Subversion or Git.

Comment: So kind of you to say.  Thank you.  I'm glad you found it helpful.